# Slicing Level Surfaces

Tags: calculus, surfaces

[image: MATH PROBLEM]

How do I properly do questions like these? I simply each equation by inputting the value into the variable but after that I am confused as to what I am supposed to do after?

Comment: When you put in, for example, $x=0$ then you have $5y^{2}+z^{2}=4$. Is this an equation of a circle? An ellipse? What are the coordinates where it intercepts the other axes?

Comment: Where is it from? Could you give us the source of the problem?

Comment: It is the equation of an ellipse but I am unsure of how to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

After you replace the variable, you look at the curve in the plane that you get. For instance, in the first case you put $z=1.5$, and you get 
$$
2x^2+5y^2+2.25=4,
$$
or 
$$
2x^2+5y^2=1.75.
$$
We may rewrite this as 
$$
\frac{x^2}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{1.75}}{\sqrt2}\right)^2}+\frac{y^2}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{1.75}}{\sqrt5}\right)^2}=1,
$$
where we see that get an ellipse centered at the origin crossing the $x$-axis at $\pm\frac{\sqrt{1.75}}{\sqrt2}\simeq\pm0.94$ and the $y$-axis at $\pm\frac{\sqrt{1.75}}{\sqrt5}\simeq\pm0.6$, which seems to be D in your options.

Comment: I'm confused about how you got your simplification at the end?

Comment: You mean this? $$\frac{x^2}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{1.75}}{\sqrt2}\right)^2}=\frac{2x^2}{1.75}.$$

Comment: Yes, how did you go from 2x^2+5y^2 = 1.75 to the the rewritten equation at the end. did you set x or y to 0 then solve for each variable independently?

Comment: Still not sure if you are talking about the equation of the ellipse, or its intercepts.

Comment: Both of them. For the interepts did you just set one of the variable equal to 0 and then just solve for it and for the equation how did you get that answer?

Comment: Yes. If $y=0$, then the equation becomes $$\frac{x^2}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{1.75}}{\sqrt2}\right)^2}=1,$$ so $${x^2}={\left(\frac{\sqrt{1.75}}{\sqrt2}\right)^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you one last question if we are plotting the z-intercept would that just go on the regular y-axis?, what I mean by this is in the equation 2x^2 + z^2 = 1.1875 we have a clear x and z intercept. So would the x intercept go on the x axis and the z go on the y-axis?

Comment: You can name the variables any way you want. When you are doing $x$ and $z$, you need to display things in the $xz$-plane. Drawing it in perspective at an angle will give you nothing, though, so you just draw it as a plane.